# How to make data-original attribute ignored by XHTML Basic 1.1?

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a website with lazyLoading images that use the attribute data-original that is specific for HTML5. It works fine on mobiles but validators error that it's invalid. So how to make data-original valid in XHTML Basic 1.1 or make it be ignored or make other work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XHTML Basic 1.1 defines a formal syntax. The only way to make an attribute that is not valid by that syntax is to have the syntax changed. This won’t happen, since nobody is working on XHTML Basic, so you can’t even make a suggestion on a change; the XHTML2 working group that produced the spec was [closed in 2010](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/).